# VirtualBox no network device found

Tags: android, networking, virtualbox

- I have just installed **windows 10**
- And top of it **Oracal Virtual Box 4.3.3**
- Now when i m trying to set Bridge Adapter there is no network device available
- Ether wifi or lan both are empty in name section
- When i will go to network section of Vbox and select Bridge Adapter**strong text** it gives me **Invalid setting Detected** Error
- There is one more pop up menu says **No bridges network adapter is currently selected**
- i have checked my drivers every driver version is latest updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved by:

- uninstall VirtualBox 4.3.30
- restart Windows
- install VirtualBox 5.0.0

Maybe it's just a restart what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to updating to Windows 10, it seems that any virtual adapter needs to be uninstalled other your computer will have no network connections at all and you'll have to roll back the update or reset and re-install all of your software.  This includes Virtual Box, Sonic VPN, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid settings detected" - one reason may be because there is no motherboard memory left.

Go to Settings-->System-->Motherboard, and reduce the base memory. Like for me it was fully utilized and I changed it from 100% to almost 50%, like below and it worked. :-)

[image]